# How to mock constant in angular unittest?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a controller which has 1 dependency which is a constant called constantData:

```
$scope.selectInputs = {
    states: constantData().statesTerritories()
};
```

The constantData looks something like:

```
.constant('constantData', function(){
    return {
        statesTerritories: function(){
            return  [
                        { name:'NSW' },
                        { name:'ACT' },
                        { name:'VIC' },
                        { name:'QLD' },
                        { name:'WA' },
                        { name:'SA' },
                        { name:'TAS' },
                        { name:'NT' }
                    ];
        },
```

In my unit test I have:

```
constantData = {statesTerritories: function () {
            }};

            spyOn(constantData, 'statesTerritories').andReturn(
                function () {
                    return    [
                        { name:'NSW' },
                        { name:'ACT' },
                        { name:'VIC' }
                    ];
                }
            );
```

But the error I am getting with karma is:

```
TypeError: '[object Object]' is not a function (evaluating 'constantData()')
```

How can I mockout this constant in my test?

Comment: You can't do constantData().whatever because constantData is an object instead of a function. Try with $scope.selectInputs = {
    states: constantData.statesTerritories()
};

Comment: Why is constantData() an object?

Comment: Because you are asigning an object to it: constantData = { whatever };

Comment: thanks dude it worked